# JavaScript/HTML - Keeping numeric values from select dropdown list selected

Tags: javascript, html, session-storage

I am keeping the values of my `option` HTML tags selected using this code:

```
document.getElementById('select_itens_op').onchange = function() {
   sessionStorage.setItem('pagina', document.getElementById('select_itens_op').value);
};

if (sessionStorage.getItem('pagina')) {
   document.getElementById('select_itens_op').options[sessionStorage.getItem('pagina')].selected = true;
}
```

It was working just fine, but in one of my tags I came across with a problem. The `option` tags have numeric values and when I reload the page, what it's being kept is the `option` related to the index of the value stored in the `sessionStorage`.

Example:

```
<select name="select_itens_op" id="select_itens_op" ">
   <option value="">Página</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="8">8</option>
   <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

If I select the option with value `2`, this value will be stored into the sessionStorage, but when I refresh the page the option selected will be the one with value `4`, since it is the `position 2` of the list. If I select `4` the value stored will be `4` and the option returned would be `10`, and so on.

If I use string values it works great, provided I add `ids` to these tags, but I need these numeric values. I already made my research and I didn't find a proper answer.

What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: Instead of doing .selected, could you try el.value = val from session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go for `SelectElement.value` directly:

```js
const el_op = document.getElementById('select_itens_op');

// Set on init
if (sessionStorage.pagina) el_op.value = sessionStorage.pagina;
// Store on change
el_op.addEventListener('change', () => sessionStorage.pagina = el_op.value );
```